# Converting .pbf to postgresql using osm2pgsql (not enough disk space)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I must say I don't understand this completely.

But when I try to convert a binary pbf file for my country Germany which is of size 3gb using osm2pgsql (slim mode), it is converted to postgresql tables for 3 hours and fails with the message 'not enough disk space'. I have 50gb of free space in my linux machine.

I can understand the temporary files are added to RAM normally and because I am using slim mode it is saved to database.

Please enlighten me, how a 3gb osm file while converting to postgresql(gis) tables takes 50gb space and throws that error ?

How do I solve this ?

Comment: PBF files are compressed. The uncompressed data is much larger.

Comment: Yes but does 3gb go beyond 50gb while decompressing it ? Is there no way to convert this mapdata to postgresql other than increasing my harddisk space ?

Comment: Not sure. stackoverfow is the wrong place for this question. Try http://help.openstreetmap.org/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: New question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224381/converting-pbf-to-postgresql-using-osm2pgsql-not-enough-disk-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it could cross 50gb. As India pbf is around 375mb and PostgreSQL data folder size is 11gb that include world boundary also from OSM.